# Getting the width of a column header

Tags: java, jdbc, resize, columnheader

I am trying to resize my columns based on both column headers and column width.

I have had some success with this, however it is only a temporary solution really.

The min width I'm setting is only for one table, however I am previewing many tables with different column headers, so sometimes this min width will be too small. I wanted a way of getting the column header width for the smallest column header and assign it to this variable.

```
final TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
                    for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) 
                    {
                        int width = 70; // Min width
                        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) 
                        {
                            TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                            Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                            width = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width +1 , width);
                        }
                        columnModel.getColumn(column).setPreferredWidth(width);
                    }
```

UPDATE:

I have tried using the DefaultTableCellRenderer for the column it is looping through, then getting the column header width and applying that to the variable, but it came with this result

[image]

```
final TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
                    for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) 
                    {
                        DefaultTableCellRenderer colwidth=((DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer());
                        int width = colwidth.getWidth();
                        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) 
                        {
                            TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                            Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                            width = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width +1 , width);
                        }
                        columnModel.getColumn(column).setPreferredWidth(width);
                    }
```

Comment: I think [Set a column width of JTable according to the text in a header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378506/set-a-column-width-of-jtable-according-to-the-text-in-a-header) question may help you.

Comment: @notmyf4ulty , I have tried searching for about 3 hours this morning and I have come across all variations of my question. Unfortunately, none really helped.

Answer (score 0):

table.getColumnModel().getColumn("column that you want").getPreferredWidth();